# All LineChartDataset values are not plotting in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-charts

HI i'm working in line chart for my app, In this i loaded the

```
LineChartDataSet *set1 = [[LineChartDataSet alloc] initWithValues:yValue label:@"Name"]; 
LineChartData *data = [[LineChartData alloc] initWithDataSet:set1]; 
self.lineChartView.data = data;
```

my yValue are
entries:

```
ChartDataEntry, x: 4.16, y 39.77
ChartDataEntry, x: 15.05, y 48.19
ChartDataEntry, x: 18.16, y 55.23
ChartDataEntry, x: 17.2, y 55.24
ChartDataEntry, x: 19.02, y 57.55
ChartDataEntry, x: 24.55, y 63.12
ChartDataEntry, x: 34.22, y 74.92
ChartDataEntry, x: 40.15, y 79.42
ChartDataEntry, x: 45.17, y 80.7
ChartDataEntry, x: 56.33, y 83.91 .....
```

for this first three to four values are not plotting

[image]

help me..

Comment: Please accept the answer if it helped you, If not please provide further details about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your problem seems to be the x-axis, you have 200 between the lines on the x-axis and since some points are close to each other, and you are drawing 10 points on a very little space, they don´t show up using the scale of 200. 
To change the scale to 0 to 50:

```
 ChartXAxis *xAxis = self.lineChartView.xAxis;
 xAxis.axisMinimum = 0.0;
 xAxis.axisMaximum = 50.0;
```

To make the chart scrollable to right and left, you can add this (and the chart will show only values up to 10 on the first screen, then by scrolling you will see more values):

```
 [self.lineChartView setVisibleXRangeMaximum:10]  
 [self.lineChartView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```